# Matlab 3d plot of indexed data

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I am trying to plot a 3d view of a very large CT dataset. My data is in a 3d matrix of 2000x2000x1000 dimension. The object is surrounded by air, which is set to NaN in my matrix.

I would like to be able to see the greyscale value of the surface of the object (no isosurface) but I cannot quite work out how to do that in Matlab. Can anyone help me please?

Given that I a dealing with a huge matrix and I am only interested in the surface of the object, does anyone know a good trick how to reduce the size of my dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working:

```
function [X,Y,Z,C] = extract_surface(file_name,slice_number,voxel_size)
LT          = imread(file_name);%..READ THE 2D MAP
BW          = im2bw(LT,1);%..THRESHOLD TO BINARY
B           = bwboundaries(BW,8,'noholes');%..FIND THE OUTLINE OF THE IMAGE
X           = B{1}(:,1);%..EXTRACT X AND Y COORDINATES
Y           = B{1}(:,2);
indices     = sub2ind(size(LT),X,Y);%..FIND THE CORRESPONDING LINEAR INDICES
C           = LT(indices);%..NOW READ THE VALUES AT THE OUTLINE POSITION
Z           = ones(size(X))*slice_number;
```

I can then plot this with

```
figure
scatter3(X,Y,Z,2,C)
```

Now the only thing I could improve is to have all these points in the scatter plot connected with a surface. @upperBound you suggested `delaunay3` for this purpose - I cannot quite figure out how to do this. Do you have a tip?

Comment: OK, this seems to work `tri     = delaunay(X,Y);` followed by `trisurf(tri,X,Y,Z,C,'EdgeAlpha',0,'FaceColor','interp')`. @upperBound: However, the resulting surface has artefacts and I get this message: 
"Warning: Duplicate data points have been detected.
Some data points do not map to vertices in the triangulation.
To avoid this behavior, call UNIQUE on the data points prior to calling DELAUNAY.". This is presumably because the outline in the different slices are quite similar in x and y coordinates between adjacent z-slices. I cannot use UNIQUE, what can I do? Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

The function surf(X,Y,Z) allows you to plot 3d data, where (X,Y) gives the coordinates in the x-y-plane while Z gives the z-coordinate and the surface color.

By default the function does not plot anything for the NaN entries, so you should be good to go with the surf function.

To set the surf-function to use a grayscale plotting use:

```
surf(matrix3d);
colormap(gray);
```

This plots the matrix in a surface plot and sets the colormap to grayscale.

In addition, as I understand your data, you might be able to eliminate entire plane-segments in your matrix. If for instance the plane A(1,1:2000,1:1000) is NaN in all entries you could eliminate all those entries (thus the entire Y,Z-plane in entry X=1). This will however require some heavy for loops, which might be over the top. This depends on how many data matrices you have compared to how many different plot you want for each matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you some ideas. I assume lack of a direct 3D "surface detector".

Since you have a 3D matrix where XY-planes are CT scan slices and each slice is an image, I would try to find edges of each slice say with [edge](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/edge.html). This would require some preprocessing like first thresholding each slice image. Then I can either use [scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html) to display the edge data as a 3D point cloud or [delaunay3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay3.html) to display the edge data as a surface.

I hope this will help you achieve what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks, I think this approach is what could work well for me. I will try and construct the edge data using delaunay3. The additional challenge that I need to tackle is that my object is hollow and I only want the outside surface/edge (that should decrease the number of points to plot and speed up the visualisation). I will have a look around and get back to the thread if I found a good solution.