# (MATLAB) 3D CT image reconstruction by 2D slices

Tags: matlab, dicom

I have 2D slices of a 3D CT image. They are in `DICOM` format and there are 250 of them. I want to reconstruct the 3D image with MATLAB. How can I do this in a loop?

- I am using MATLAB R2010b on my Ubuntu system.
- Images' location is: `/home/amadeus/Desktop/images`
- Images are named:

  ```
  IM-0001-0001.dcm
  IM-0001-0002.dcm
  IM-0001-0003.dcm
  ...
  IM-0001-0250.dcm
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparantly there is a function just for reading DICOM files: [dicomread](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/dicomread.html), I suggest using that to load the images and then store them in a 3D matrix. [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) can be used to construct the filenames of the images (use `%04d` to generate four-digit number with leading zeros).

Assuming all images are aligned and have same size:

```
N = 250;
img_dir = '/home/amadeus/Desktop/images'

% read the first image separately just to get the size
strfile = 'IM-0001-0001.dcm';
img = dicomread(fullfile(img_dir, strfile));
siz_img = size(img);

% create result matrix:
ct3d = NaN([siz_img N]);
ct3d(:,:,1) = img;    

% load all the remaining images and put them in the matrix
for ii=2:N
    strfile = sprintf('IM-0001-%04d.dcm',ii);
    ct3d(:,:,ii)= dicomread(fullfile(img_dir, strfile));
end
```

edit:
This assumes image are grayscale (2d). In case they're full colour (width x height x 3), you should add another colon operator in the assignment to `ct3d`.

Comment: First of all I would like to thank you so much for your help. It has been only a day I started using MATLAB and for now everything seems so complicated to me. I got some errors with the code: first one was: ct3d = NaN([siz N]); ??? Undefined function or variable 'siz'. Because of the reason that I do not know how to fix it, I directly used ct3d = NaN([250]); But then: ct3d(:,:,1) = img;    
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch. How should I fix this error? Again, I am so much thankful for your help.

Comment: yeah, I noticed my error, used `siz` instead of `siz_img` :( fixed now !

Comment: you are the best!! one last question: how can I view my ct3d file now? = ) imshow does not work.

Comment: it _is_ 3d data, so visualizing it on a 2d screen is not straightforward + even in 3d, some parts/voxels may obstruct other parts/voxels.. I recently had a tour of the ct department at a local hospital and the guy there said that they usually visualize a 3d scan by slicing the 3d data (under angle not necessarily equal to scanning angle) and scrolling through the slices. Other method may be: extract the feature to visualize and show that as a surface or something similar (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101701/matlab-3d-plot-of-indexed-data)

Comment: If you want to visualize slices of your 3D image where the intensity crosses some threshold, take a look at MATLAB function isosurface http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html